# Iterate through DIV Class using selenium on page

Tags: python, selenium

I'm looking to iterate through a set of rows on a page using selenium to scrape live results from the page in a quick manner. I have a code which appears to return the first row and print it, but doesn't look to be iterating through the set.

```
content = [browser.find_element_by_class_name('event')]
rows = [browser.find_elements_by_class_name('event__match')]

for rows in content:
    goals = {}
    goals['Home'] = rows.find_element_by_class_name("event__participant--home").text.strip()
    goals['Away'] = rows.find_element_by_class_name("event__participant--away").text.strip()
    goals['hScore'] = rows.find_element_by_class_name("event__scores").text.split("-")[1]
    goals['aScore'] = rows.find_element_by_class_name("event__scores").text.split("-")[-1]



    print(goals['Home'],goals['aScore'],goals['aScore'],goals['Away'])
```

gets me the result;

```
Team 1 
0
0 Team 2
```

Which would be the expected result when it's only one match on the page - but there's 50 at the moment.

I feel like I'm missing something in my method here, it could be pretty simple and staring me in the face so apologies if that's the case!

Comment: What `event` and `event__match` elements are?

Comment: Event div is a container div which houses all the rows, event__match is the div class of all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistake is in `for rows in content:`, where content is parent div and you need rows. To iterate all through rows use code below:

```
rows = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('event__match')

for row in rows:
    goals = {}
    goals['Home'] = row.find_element_by_class_name("event__participant--home").text.strip()
    goals['Away'] = row.find_element_by_class_name("event__participant--away").text.strip()
    goals['hScore'] = row.find_element_by_class_name("event__scores").text.split("-")[1]
    goals['aScore'] = row.find_element_by_class_name("event__scores").text.split("-")[-1]

    print(goals['Home'],goals['aScore'],goals['aScore'],goals['Away'])
```